# MetricKit MXCallStackTree symbolication

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode12, symbolicatecrash

I am trying to implement MetricKit so later I could analyze `MXCrashDiagnostic` and `MXHangDiagnostic` reports. However when I am triggering a test crash,  Here is an example of what I get for `MXCrashDiagnostic`:

```
ente  "timeStampEnd": "2021-06-07 15:59:00 +0000",
"crashDiagnostics": [
  {
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "callStackTree": {
      "callStacks": [
        {
          "threadAttributed": true,
          "callStackRootFrames": [
            {
              "binaryUUID": "DC2EACEA-3D9C-3409-96C2-2DF9C89AD19D",
              "offsetIntoBinaryTextSegment": 6917586944,
              "sampleCount": 1,
              "subFrames": [
                {
                  "binaryUUID": "DC2EACEA-3D9C-3409-96C2-2DF9C89AD19D",
                  "offsetIntoBinaryTextSegment": 6917586944,
                  "sampleCount": 1,
                  "subFrames": [
                    {
                      "binaryUUID": "DC2EACEA-3D9C-3409-96C2-2DF9C89AD19D",
                      "offsetIntoBinaryTextSegment": 6917586944,
                      "sampleCount": 1,
                      "subFrames": [
                        {
                          "binaryUUID": "35463E49-9534-3644-B993-2A73C287A143",
                          "offsetIntoBinaryTextSegment": 4329963520,
                          "sampleCount": 1,
                          "binaryName": "demo",
                          "address": 4333717704
                          }]
```

I tried to symbolicate the the data, by executing commands:

```
atos -arch arm64e -o /Users/xxx/Downloads/\!dsym-4/demo.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/demo 4333717704
```

But I can't find the crash stack and the result returned is`4333717704`

the DSYM file uuid is`UUID: 35463E49-9534-3644-B993-2A73C287A143 (arm64) /Users/xxx/Downloads/!dsym-3/demo.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/demo`

How should the stack returned by MetricKit be symbolicated?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I'm not at all surprised you're having issues. I think everyone that tries to symbolicate MetricKit data runs into problems.

The reason is the `offsetIntoBinaryTextSegment` field is incorrectly named. It's actually the binary load address! It took me forever to figure this out. I've filed a bug with Apple, and I suggest you do this same. (though I don't have high hopes, as this JSON structure is effectively an API)

What you want to do is:

```
atos -arch ARCH -i -l <offsetIntoBinaryTextSegment> /path/to/dsym <address>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `offsetIntoBinaryTextSegment` field instead of `address`. [`MXCallStackTree`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metrickit/mxcallstacktree/3552293-jsonrepresentation?language=objc) explain the meaning of each field. It tells us `offsetIntoBinaryTextSegment` is the address of symbol. `address` is the address of stack frame in memory.
2. Convert 10-base to Hex. `atos` only accepts Hex address.
3. `atos --help` would tell you that two address arguments are needed. `loadAddress` after `-l` is your Binary Image load address. `address` is symbol offset(`offsetIntoBinaryTextSegment`) + loadAddress. See [crash report symbolication](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/adding-identifiable-symbol-names-to-a-crash-report?language=objc). In MXCallStackTree, we do not know Binary Image load address like crash report. But it is not necessary. `atos` only cares `address - loadAddress == offsetIntoBinaryTextSegment`. A trick in your situation is `loadAddress=0x1` and `address=hex(offsetIntoBinaryTextSegment + 1)`. Therefore, the command line would be, `0x102160000 = hex(4329963520)`:

```
atos -arch arm64e -o /Users/xxx/Downloads/!dsym-4/demo.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/demo 0x1 0x102160001
```

This discussion might help you too: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/681967